# Small sample, many variables

Tags: small-sample, composite

I am working on some applied research. I have a small non-random sample ($n=90$), and many variables $>50$ IVs (mix of nominal, ordinal, interval) and 6DVs. The data collection instrument itself was obviously broad (but items chosen were due to known relationships or theorised relationships in the past) so as to make the most use of a time-poor population. It was also envisaged that groups of items would represent a common construct (no scale currently exists). What I am left with now, however, is a wealth of data for such a small sample.

In an effort to minimise the data, I have conducted principal components analysis on those variables (checking factorability statistics) that were thought to tap common constructs and produced composite variables. These were checked for internal consistency, some of these were reliable $a>.70$, some were not. Composite scores were averaged to apply equal weights (conservative as no prior research done using these previously).

I would like to know how the frequency of performance or use of IVs relates to methods of communication (DVs). Ideally, I'd like to know how each IV relates to the DVs. However, multiple testing correction is obviously an issue here. But if I correct, my p value will be so small that I will have no chance of finding a significant effect.

I feel as though I am already taking a 'shortcut' by using ordinal measures (likert) as interval (under direction) - another reason for the creation of composite scores.

**My question/s are (finally): What should I do now in light of my original goals (correlation/regression)? Should I run them all, not correct and emphasise its exploratory nature OR should I select a small number of variables (probably the composites for higher reliability) and develop a new, smaller model to test?**

I obviously want the result to be as rigorous as possible, not misleading in it's use of and reporting of statistics and make some sort of contribution to my area. However, every corner I turn I hit a wall. The majority of literature in my area often uses likert as interval and rarely reports multiple testing correction, but that doesn't make it sit better with me.

Comment: I am afraid that as your sample selection was non-random, I don't think you can get anything reliable from any analysis, however, you can still run your analyses for exploratory purposes to identify potential relationships for further study with a more rigorous randomisation of the next sample.  In this case even a P of <0.3 or >0.7 might be of interest.